# reading from a particular part of a line to the end (JAVA)

Tags: java

I have a text file. each line is a slightly different length. i want to read for the 44th character of each line to the end of the line. working fine for some line but getting a out of bounds error for others.

```
int lineNumber = 0;

        ArrayList<String> SenState = new ArrayList<String>();
        while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            lineNumber++;
            if (lineNumber >= 24) {
            String temp = line.substring(44, 46);//error occurs here for int 46
                SenState.add(temp);
                    }
                }
```

below is part of the text file i am reading from. i just need to get the Val of each line

```
Start time              End time                ID  Val
--------------------    --------------------    --  ---
25-Feb-2008 00:20:14    25-Feb-2008 00:22:57    24  1
25-Feb-2008 09:33:41    25-Feb-2008 09:33:42    24  1
25-Feb-2008 09:33:47    25-Feb-2008 17:21:12    24  1
25-Feb-2008 09:36:43    25-Feb-2008 09:37:04    5   1
25-Feb-2008 09:37:20    25-Feb-2008 09:37:23    6   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (line.lenght() > 44) {
    String temp = line.substring(44);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> i want to read for the 44th character of each line to the end of the line

Then just call [`String.substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-):

```
String temp = line.substring(44);
```

I strongly suspect the issue with your current code is that it's expecting to get 2 characters, when a value of 1 only has a single character. Index 46 is out of range.

(Additionally, I'd strongly advise you to follow Java naming conventions - `SenState` should be `senState` - or better, something which clearly indicates the meaning.)

Comment: when i do that i reads either the last character of the ID column or the Val column so it works for some lines not all

Comment: @McCann46: I don't understand what you mean, but that code *does* read the line from index 44 onwards. Note that in your sample data, your Val column is at index 52, not 44...